# Spacing Issue in HTML email with Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2011

I have an email I'm sending out which I originally designed in mailchimp and then extracted the code from there to further customize it. I have a two column header in where the logo is on the left & social icons on the right. I tested it on emailonacid and all tests look great except that on Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013, the LOGO is no longer bottom aligned with the social icons. On Outlook 2011 and all other email clients like Yahoo, Gmail, etc, it looks fine. Is there a specific reason why it looks okay in 2011, but not the other versions of Outlook? And is there a specific fix?

I've included screenshots of what the header should look like vs what it looks like in certain Outlook clients. I've also attached the code here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraph.org/schema/" >
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Subject of Email Goes Here">
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="43929265776">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"><!-- NAME: 1 COLUMN -->
<!--[if gte mso 15]>
                <xml>
                        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                        <o:AllowPNG/>
                        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
                        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml>
                <![endif]-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Subject of Email Goes Here</title>

<style type="text/css">
                p{
                        margin:10px 0;
                        padding:0;
                }
                table{
                        border-collapse:collapse;
                }
                h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
                        display:block;
                        margin:0;
                        padding:0;
                }
                img,a img{
                        border:0;
                        height:auto;
                        outline:none;
                        text-decoration:none;
                }
                body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
                        height:100%;
                        margin:0;
                        padding:0;
                        width:100%;
                }
                #outlook a{
                        padding:0;
                }
                img{
                        -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
                }
                table{
                        mso-table-lspace:0pt;
                        mso-table-rspace:0pt;
                }
                .ReadMsgBody{
                        width:100%;
                }
                .ExternalClass{
                        width:100%;
                }
                p,a,li,td{
                        mso-line-height-rule:exactly;
                }
                a[href^=tel],a[href^=sms]{
                        color:inherit;
                        cursor:default;
                        text-decoration:none;
                }
                p,a,li,td,body,table{
                        -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
                }
                .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font{
                        line-height:100%;
                }
                a[x-apple-data-detectors]{
                        color:inherit !important;
                        text-decoration:none !important;
                        font-size:inherit !important;
                        font-family:inherit !important;
                        font-weight:inherit !important;
                        line-height:inherit !important;
                }
                #bodyCell{
                        padding:10px;
                }
                .templateContainer{
                        max-width:600px !important;
                }
                a.mcnButton{
                        display:block;
                }
                .mcnImage{
                        vertical-align:bottom;
                }
                .mcnTextContent{
                        word-break:break-word;
                }
                .mcnTextContent img{
                        height:auto !important;
                }
                .mcnDividerBlock{
                        table-layout:fixed !important;
                }
                body,#bodyTable{
                        background-color:#e6e6e6;
                }
                #bodyCell{
                        border-top:0;
                }
                .templateContainer{
                        border:0;
                }
                h1{
                        color:#002664;
                        font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        font-size:18px;
                        font-style:normal;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        line-height:150%;
                        letter-spacing:normal;
                        text-align:left;
                }

                #templatePreheader{
                        background-color:#FAFAFA;
                        border-top:0;
                        border-bottom:0;
                        padding-top:0px;
                        padding-bottom:0px;
                }
                #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p{
                        color:#656565;
                        font-family:Helvetica;
                        font-size:10px;
                        line-height:150%;
                        text-align:left;
                }
                #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent a,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p a{
                        color:#E6E6E6;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        text-decoration:underline;
                }
                #templateHeader{
                        background-color:#FFFFFF;
                        border-top:0;
                        border-bottom:0;
                        padding-top:9px;
                        padding-bottom:0;
                }
                #templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{
                        color:#202020;
                        font-family:Helvetica;
                        font-size:16px;
                        line-height:150%;
                        text-align:left;
                }
                #templateHeader .mcnTextContent a,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p a{
                        color:#2BAADF;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        text-decoration:underline;
                }
                #templateBody{
                        background-color:#FFFFFF;
                        border-top:0;
                        border-bottom:2px solid #EAEAEA;
                        padding-top:0;
                        padding-bottom:9px;
                }
                #templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{
                        color:#202020;
                        font-family:Helvetica;
                        font-size:14px;
                        line-height:150%;
                        text-align:left;
                }
                #templateBody .mcnTextContent a,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p a{
                        color:#0060a9;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        text-decoration:none;
                }
                #templateFooter{
                        background-color:#FAFAFA;
                        border-top:0;
                        border-bottom:0;
                        padding-top:9px;
                        padding-bottom:9px;
                }
                #templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{
                        color:#656565;
                        font-family:Helvetica;
                        font-size:12px;
                        line-height:150%;
                        text-align:center;
                }
                #templateFooter .mcnTextContent a,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p a{
                        color:#656565;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        text-decoration:underline;
                }
        @media only screen and (min-width:768px){
                .templateContainer{
                        width:600px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                body,table,td,p,a,li{
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                body{
                        width:100% !important;
                        min-width:100% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #bodyCell{
                        padding-top:10px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImage{
                        width:100% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnCaptionTopContent,.mcnCaptionBottomContent,.mcnTextContentContainer,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer,.mcnImageGroupContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftTextContentContainer{
                        max-width:100% !important;
                        width:100% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .textContentContainerLeft{
                max-width: 65% !important;
                width: 65% !important;
        }
}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .textContentContainerRight{
                max-width: 35% !important;
                width: 35% !important;
        }
}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .socialIcon {
                height: 18px !important;
                width: 18px !important;
        }
}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent .fillerTable p{
                line-height: 0 !important;
        }

  }     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer{
                        min-width:100% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageGroupContent{
                        padding:9px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter .mcnTextContent,.mcnCaptionRightContentOuter .mcnTextContent{
                        padding-top:9px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageCardTopImageContent,.mcnCaptionBlockInner .mcnCaptionTopContent:last-child .mcnTextContent{
                        padding-top:18px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageCardBottomImageContent{
                        padding-bottom:9px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageGroupBlockInner{
                        padding-top:0 !important;
                        padding-bottom:0 !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageGroupBlockOuter{
                        padding-top:9px !important;
                        padding-bottom:9px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentColumn{
                        padding-right:18px !important;
                        padding-left:18px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnImageCardLeftImageContent,.mcnImageCardRightImageContent{
                        padding-right:18px !important;
                        padding-bottom:0 !important;
                        padding-left:18px !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcpreview-image-uploader{
                        display:none !important;
                        width:100% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                h1{
                        font-size:22px !important;
                        line-height:125% !important;
                }

}      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent p{
                        font-size:14px !important;
                        line-height:150% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #templatePreheader{
                        display:block !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p{
                        font-size:14px !important;
                        line-height:150% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{
                        font-size:16px !important;
                        line-height:150% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{
                        font-size:16px !important;
                        line-height:150% !important;
                }

}       @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                #templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{
                        font-size:14px !important;
                        line-height:150% !important;
                }

}
</style>
</head>
<body style="height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; background-color:#e6e6e6; " ><div ><div class="mktEditable" ><center>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;width:
100%;background-color: #e6e6e6;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 10px;width: 100%;border-top: 0;"><!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                                <![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;border: 0;max-width: 600px !important;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="templatePreheader" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #e6e6e6;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 0px;"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
        <![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;max-width: 600px !important;">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="bottom" class="preheaderContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;" valign="bottom">
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65%" class="mcnTextContentContainer textContentContainerLeft" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color: #1e3b8b;font-size: 1px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;word-break: break-word;font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="10" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock fillerTable" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;" valign="bottom">  <p style="font-size: 2px;line-height: 50%">&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<span style="display:none; color: #1e3b8b; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; text-decoration: none; max-height:0px ;max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;"><!-- PREVIEW TEXT -->Email Previw Text Here</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="90" valign="bottom" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left: 18px;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 11px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;word-break: break-word;font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;vertical-align: bottom;" valign="bottom"><br><a target="_blank" href="http://placehold.it"><img alt="LOGO HERE" src="http://placehold.it/200x75?text=LOGO" style="max-width: 200px;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage" width="200" align="absbottom"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="35%" height="50" class="mcnTextContentContainer textContentContainerRight" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-right: 18px;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 11px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;word-break: break-word;font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 150%;text-align: right;">
<br>
<a href="{{system.viewAsWebpageLink}}" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #656565;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">View this email in your browser</a><br><br>
<div style="color: #E6E6E6; text-align: right;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #e6e6e6;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b7054fb8f7e8331b3b8deed4a/images/2d3db039-eb85-4a61-8fd9-3a8bd68abba3.png" alt="Facebook" style="width: 17px;height: 17px;margin: 0px;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" align="none" height="17" width="17"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #e6e6e6;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b7054fb8f7e8331b3b8deed4a/images/2a87b54c-f615-43a3-bc82-34508a88a4a0.png" alt="Twitter" style="width: 17px;height: 17px;margin: 0px;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" align="none" height="17" width="17"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" id="templateHeader" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0;">
<table class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" class="mcnImageBlockInner" valign="top">
<table class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;text-align: center;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><a target="_blank"
href="https://placehold.it"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/600x300" style="max-width: 600px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline
!important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="mcnImage" align="middle" width="600"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" id="templateBody" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 2px solid #EAEAEA;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 9px;">
<table class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;table-layout: fixed !important;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%;padding: 0px 18px 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="mcnTextBlockInner" valign="top" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" class="mcnTextContentContainer" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 25px 9px 25px;font-family: Arial,'helvetica neue',helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;word-break: break-word;color: #202020;text-align: left;"
valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mauris est, iaculis elementum neque fringilla quis. Aliquam id maximus magna, vitae dapibus quam. Nulla ex justo, imperdiet vitae erat eget, maximus auctor mi. Praesent a turpis fringilla, venenatis risus eget, varius turpis. Etiam pellentesque auctor tempus.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;table-layout: fixed !important;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%;padding: 0px 18px 10px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
                                                <![endif]-->
<!-- // END TEMPLATE --></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshots below.

[Normal view, including Outlook 2011](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeyFU.png)

[Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwuuW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using aligned tables to get things to stack in mobile, the sum of the two tables' widths cannot add up to 100% or Outlook will do what you're seeing. You need something like 15 to 20 empty pixels between the tables. Try making the widths 63% and 33% instead of 65 and 35.

Alternatively, you can put a ghost cell break between the two tables, eg:
    `<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td><![endif]-->`
to force Outlook two view the layout as two cells rather than two floating tables.