# outlook html signature showing gaps and white spaces between slices

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, whitespace, signature

I recently made an email signature using photoshop (slicing method), it's working fine on Gmail and even in my server (Roundcube) except for outlook, it's showing a white space between every slice.. how can I fix that please, it's been a week now since I'm trying to fix this.. I need your help...

some people suggested that I need to remove white space between every td I also tried the display: block; tried even to make my signature smaller tried changing the background and still nothing.

i'm gonna need your help guys.

I attached down below, the HTML code I'm using for my signature along with a screenshot showing the white spaces.

thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot of my signature on outlook]

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
    img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head>
<!-- Paste Code Under This Line
_________________________________________________________________________________ -->
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (signature.psd) -->
<table id="Tableau_01" width="500" height="153" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XqrxsnJw/moshe-01.png" width="166" height="153" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Vv2gT2r2/moshe-02.png" width="334" height="54" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="mailto:moshe@accutures.com"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XNPspBHx/moshe-03.png" width="334" height="30" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="tel:+972-545994273"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fT0BXW1s/moshe-04.png" width="334" height="27" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.accutures.com"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T3MQcMXD/moshe-05.png" width="210" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/moshebazer/"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nh42RRHw/moshe-06.png" width="124" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/d0JBz23Q/moshe-07.png" width="334" height="13" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
<!-- Keep Pasted Code Above This Line!
_________________________________________________________________________________ -->
</html>
```

Comment: You posted exactly the same question just a few days ago: [html email signature in outlook is showing a lot of white spaces and gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660587/html-email-signature-in-outlook-is-showing-a-lot-of-white-spaces-and-gaps)

Comment: You are missing display block on your images.

Comment: @Syfer i tried that too, didn't work. any other suggestion ?

Comment: @MosheKatz I know, but I didn't get any valuable answers, I need more suggestions.